# How to retrieve last 2 records in a table using JPA in Java

Tags: mysql, eclipselink

I am trying to retrieve the last 5 inserted data in the 'Vulcano' table from the 'Execution' table, am using EclipseLink, Facade class which calls this query at the moment;

Here is part of the Facade class am using;

```
    public ArrayList<ExecutionPOJO> getLatestsVulcanoExecutions() {
    ArrayList<ExecutionPOJO> vulcanoExecutions = new ArrayList<ExecutionPOJO>();
    //SELECT x FROM Magazine x order by x.title asc, x.price desc

   **List<Execution> excutionVulcanoList = em.createQuery("select s from Execution s order by s.vulcano_idVulcanoID desc limit 2 ").getResultList();**
```

If I use the above query I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [select s from Execution s order by s.vulcano desc limit 2], line 1, column 50: syntax error at [limit].
Internal Exception: MismatchedTokenException(80!=-1)
```

But if I remove the limit tag I get this error;

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-8021] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Error compiling the query [select s from Execution s order by s.vulcano desc], line 1, column 36: invalid ORDER BY item [s.vulcano] of type [uk.ac.aston.tomtom.entity.Vulcano], expected expression of an orderable type.
```

.

```
@Entity
public class Execution implements Serializable {
    ...
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int idExecution;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Vulcano.class)
private Vulcano vulcano;

*//Few others @ManyToOne 
//also @oneToMany*

    public Vulcano getVulcano() {
    return vulcano;
}

public void setVulcano(Vulcano vulcano) {
    this.vulcano = vulcano;
  }

//other getter and setter
}
```

Here is another entity;

```
@Entity
public class Vulcano implements Serializable {
   ...
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int idVulcano;

@OneToMany(targetEntity=Execution.class, mappedBy="vulcano", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Execution> executions;

    public List<Execution> getExecutions() {
    return executions;
}

public void setExecutions(List<Execution> executions) {
    this.executions = executions;
}

//other getters and setters
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM Magazine x order by x.title asc, x.price desc
```

instead of

```
SELECT x from Magazine x ...
```

Comment: wont be able to use star, as it threw an error;

Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [select * from Execution s order by s.vulcano desc], line 1, column 7: unexpected token [*].

Comment: @user1321704: select the columns you want to read like `select col1, col2, col3 from Magazine order by title asc, price desc`

Answer (score 0):

Limit is not a part of JPQL and so cannot be used.  Instead, you would call setMaxResults on the query to limit results returned.

Or you can use a native SQL query where Select * would work using the EntityManager createNativeQuery api instead of createQuery.